# MySQL UPDATE + PHP + HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am a beginner to PHP.
I want to make an HTML-form, that updates data in database. This is the form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Apartments</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test_upd.php" method="POST">
        <p>Введите данные, которые вы хотите изменить:</p>
        <p>Фамилия <input type="text" name="nm" size="10"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is script:

```
<?php
    $n = $_POST['nm'];
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('apartments', $link) or die(mysql_error());
    $query = "UPDATE Customers SET name (".$n");" //Customers - table, name - column in this table 
    mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close($link);
    echo "Запись изменена!";
?>
```

But when I try to update data, I get an error... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What error do you have ?

Comment: `SET name (".$n");" ` --> `SET name ='".$n"'"` But Attention. You set the namel for all Customers in your table!!

Comment: **Stop** using the deprecated `mysql_*` API. use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Comment: you realize that you're updating your entire database. This because without a `WHERE` clause, unless that's what you want. You're also open to a serious sql injection. If you want to keep your site/db intact, don't use this without a prepared statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is complete code with mysqli connection and with few improvements. You can also use special filters in input_filter, look here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.constants.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Apartments</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="test_upd.php" method="POST">
        <p>Введите данные, которые вы хотите изменить:</p>
        <p>Фамилия <input type="text" name="nm" size="10"></p> <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'submit')) {
    $n = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nm');
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "apartments") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

    $query = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Customers SET name = ?"); //Customers - table, name - column in this table 
    $query->bind_param('s', $n);
    $query->execute();

    $mysqli->close();
    echo "Запись изменена!";
}
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe! [Don't believe it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38297105/1011527)

Comment: This will update every row in the database.

Comment: I  know these and I mentioned as well (with few improvements), he is just learning PHP, right now if you see his question he didn't even know about mysqli, I think to tell him everything at once it would be hard for him to digest/understand.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thank you for link. I just want to say attitude should be encouraging rather discouraging for beginners/self learners/starters to ask questions.

Comment: We have an obligation to teach new users how to do things correctly regardless of how overwhelming it may be. Continuing to teach dangerous coding practices is something we should not do.

Comment: @JayBlanchard code updated.

Comment: This will still update *every* row in the database which is likely not what the OP wants.